# List.files give me directory

Tags: r, function, file, parameters

i have a problem with the list.files function.
I'm trying to list all my folders in a certain directory, and for each directory, list the files.
But the problem come from the list.files fun.
I tried everything (i believe), but even if i change the different paramaters, list.files give me the folders inside my directory.
Here is my code :

```
dir_vec<-list.dirs(path="E:/Louise/", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
dir_vec
files_vec<-list.files(path = "E:/Louise/",full.names=FALSE,recursive = FALSE,include.dirs=FALSE,no.. = FALSE)
files_vec
```

and here is what it return :

```
dir_vec
[1] "NEON-DS-Field-Site-Spatial-Data" "test" "test - Copie"                   
[4] "test - Copie (2)" "test - Copie (3)"  "test - Copie (4)"               
[7] "test - Copie (5)"  "test - Copie (6)"  "test - Copie (7)"               
[10] "test - Copie (8)"
```

So it's ok, that's what i want.
But for my files :

```
files_vec
[1] "fonction.R" "Herbivores_fulldata_&subsets.R"  "month.csv"                      
[4] "month.txt"  "Month_List.txt"  "NEON-DS-Field-Site-Spatial-Data"
[7] "opti.R"  "script_NDVI.R"   "test"                           
[10] "test - Copie"   "test - Copie (2)"   "test - Copie (3)"               
[13] "test - Copie (4)"  "test - Copie (5)"  "test - Copie (6)"               
[16] "test - Copie (7)"                "test - Copie (8)"   "test.R"                         
[19] "wdL.txt"
```

All the `test`, and `test - Copie(n)` are folders.

If you know why it does this, could you explain to me, because I don't get why !

NB: If I put TRUE for recursive, it gives me the files within the different folders, so it's not what I want either.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the filenames (including directories) you can exclude the directories with `file.info`. This function returns a `data.frame` with a logical column `isdir` giving what is needed to select only files.

In the example below I will list all files in the current directory.

```
fls <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, include.dirs = FALSE)
fls[!file.info(fls)$isdir]
```